# .htaccess file is not working on go daddy server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website that is hosted on Godaddy server. For SEO I have made all the rule free from .php extension. for url rewrite i am using `.htaccess` file

`.htaccess` file is running fine on local server that is XAMPP, but on live server (godaddy server ) it is not working.

I have no idea about `.htaccess` file code

`.htaccess` file content is

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: What are your rules that *was* running fine then? I suspect those you posted is not.

Comment: The rules you show don't really *do* anything, do they?

Comment: @Pekka no these are not working on live server

Comment: Ah. You're not really using URL rewriting then, just MultiViews. Hmm, the best thing to do might be to ask GoDaddy then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i have found answer myself

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: MultiViews is installed and running by default on GoDaddy Linux Grid Hosting. It is a content negotiation system which is meant to try "best guesses". It does things like guessing that if you asked for 'testing' you might have meant the 'testing.jpg' it detects among your files.

MultiViews must be programmed with which file extensions it should pay attention. By default it deals with simpler types like htm, html, jpg, png, etc. In order to allow more file types such as php, you could use "MultiviewsMatch Any".

Comment: You may also want to look at this guide for more information on this as well: http://support.godaddy.com/godaddy/apache-multiviews/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe # there is a issue with directory settings, try placing a empty .htaccess file with RewriteEngine # or it's because of GoDaddy's setup. add Apache httpd.conf file: AllowOverride FileInfo Options" file to root directory.