# .htaccess file is not working on server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL like this

```
www.subdomain.mydomain.com/mydir/admin/index.php?page=dashboard
```

I want to have a user friendly url like this

```
www.subdomain.mydomain.com/mydir/admin/dashboard
```

How do I achieve this? I am trying with the below mentioned code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Options -MultiViews

# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(TRACE|TRACK|GET|POST|HEAD)$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

For a similar context please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151357/htaccess-file-is-not-working-on-go-daddy-server/27834681#27834681).

Comment: Its located here --> www.subdomain.mydomain.com/mydir/admin/

I tried removing RewriteBase / but that too did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews   
RewriteEngine on

# use appropriate rewrite base
RewriteBase /mydir/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(TRACE|TRACK|GET|POST|HEAD)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed? (What makes this different to the code the author posted?)

Comment: What I was getting at, was to include an explanation within your answer, to show as a helpful guide as to what's different with your code

Comment: Sorry. It works. But with one more issue. Either i give /index.php?page=dashboard or just give /dashboard both comes up. Can I have only /dashboard show up even if I enter /index.php?page=dashboard. Basically URL rewrite if index.php?page= exists

Comment: OK I have added a new rule to handle that.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. One of my URL has this /index.php?page=cfeedback&status_id=2&cf_store=8 ... After applying this htaccess it shows only /index.php?page=cfeedback in the URL. Anything can be done for this?

Comment: It is not good to add requirements from comments section. If this problem has been solved then mark it as accepted. And then create a new question for the new URL.

Comment: One thought. Can we write a condition in htaccess if the URL consists status_id and cf_store then make it this way

/cfeedback/2/8 

would that be possible?

Comment: ok sure anubhava. Will be doing that. Right away and marking this as closed.

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896720/again-a-new-htaccess-issue