# again a new .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess

One of my URL has this `/index.php?page=cfeedback&status_id=2&cf_store=8` ... After applying this **`htaccess`** it shows only `/index.php?page=cfeedback` in the URL.

 Anything can be done for this?

Some pages also are just `/index.php?page=dashboard.`

My **`.htaccess`** should support both in this fashion.

```
/dashboard for URLs /index.php?page=dashboard

/cfeedback/2/8 for URLs /index.php?page=cfeedback&status_id=2&cf_store=8
```

This is a continuation of this issue: [.htaccess file is not working on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835855/htaccess-file-is-not-at-all-working-on-godaddy-server/27840490#27840490)

My **`.htaccess code`** is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews   
RewriteEngine on

# use appropriate rewrite base
RewriteBase /mydir/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(TRACE|TRACK|GET|POST|HEAD)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

I tried adding the following code for urls having `index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2` . Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)&status_id=([\w-]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

---

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews   
RewriteEngine on

# use appropriate rewrite base
RewriteBase /mydir/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(TRACE|TRACK|GET|POST|HEAD)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)&status_id=([\w-]+)&cf_store=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)&status_id=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2&cf_store=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert new set of rules before earlier rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews   
RewriteEngine on

# use appropriate rewrite base
RewriteBase /mydir/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} (TRACE|TRACK|GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)&status_id=([\w-]+)&cf_store=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?  [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2&cf_store=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. The URL kind of works. But page does not show properly. It looses all the CSS and JS path and maps to this URL /cfeedback/4/js/inc.js where as the js resides in /js/inc.js. Anythoughts?

Comment: I tried adding the following code for urls having index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2 . Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

[code](
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([\w-]+)&status_id=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2?  [L,R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&status_id=$2 [L,QSA]
)

Comment: Have added a seperator at the end in the question

Comment: Does not work :( Have added the complete .htaccess code

Comment: When I give echo $_GET['cf_store'] it does not show up :(

Comment: /mydir/admin/cfeedback/8 <--- Thats the url

Comment: my bad. Line 23 should have been
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&cf_store=$2 [L,QSA]

Comment: There is a serious issue that I facing now. If I use this htaccess, all my POST values does not submit. But when I remove this htaccess things start working fine :( . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I fixed it. Strange. I had to remove the parameters from the form Submit and just give /cfeedback in the action. This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot Anubhava. Your suggestions were very helpful.

Comment: I am stuck with another similar issue. I have raised the ticket here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939958/again-stuck-with-htaccess